# sysfs blocks gpio pins after one minute from restart

Tags: gpio, linux, kernel, sysfs

I am using Raspberry pi 4b with `Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v7l+`. I am writing simple userspace program for control one GPIO by `ioctl()` (in my case `GPIO 13` for example). However program responses: `Device or resource busy` when I try to handle it.
The investigation shows that all pins on `gpiochip0` are occupied by `sysfs`:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio 
gpiochip0: GPIOs 0-57, parent: platform/fe200000.gpio, pinctrl-bcm2711:
 gpio-0   (ID_SDA              )
 gpio-1   (ID_SCL              )
 gpio-2   (SDA1                |sysfs               ) in  hi 
 gpio-3   (SCL1                |sysfs               ) in  hi 
 gpio-4   (GPIO_GCLK           |sysfs               ) in  hi 
 gpio-5   (GPIO5               |sysfs               ) in  hi 
 gpio-6   (GPIO6               |sysfs               ) in  hi 
 gpio-7   (SPI_CE1_N           |spi0 CS1            ) out hi ACTIVE LOW
 gpio-8   (SPI_CE0_N           |spi0 CS0            ) out hi ACTIVE LOW
 gpio-9   (SPI_MISO            |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-10  (SPI_MOSI            |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-11  (SPI_SCLK            |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-12  (GPIO12              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-13  (GPIO13              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-14  (TXD1                |sysfs               ) in  hi 
 gpio-15  (RXD1                |sysfs               ) in  hi 
 gpio-16  (GPIO16              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-17  (GPIO17              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-18  (GPIO18              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-19  (GPIO19              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-20  (GPIO20              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-21  (GPIO21              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-22  (GPIO22              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-23  (GPIO23              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-24  (GPIO24              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-25  (GPIO25              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-26  (GPIO26              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-27  (GPIO27              |sysfs               ) in  lo 
 gpio-28  (RGMII_MDIO          )
 gpio-29  (RGMIO_MDC           )
 gpio-30  (CTS0                )
 gpio-31  (RTS0                )
 gpio-32  (TXD0                )
 gpio-33  (RXD0                )
 gpio-34  (SD1_CLK             )
 gpio-35  (SD1_CMD             )
 gpio-36  (SD1_DATA0           )
 gpio-37  (SD1_DATA1           )
 gpio-38  (SD1_DATA2           )
 gpio-39  (SD1_DATA3           )
 gpio-40  (PWM0_MISO           )
 gpio-41  (PWM1_MOSI           )
 gpio-42  (STATUS_LED_G_CLK    |led0                ) out lo 
 gpio-43  (SPIFLASH_CE_N       )
 gpio-44  (SDA0                )
 gpio-45  (SCL0                )
 gpio-46  (RGMII_RXCLK         )
 gpio-47  (RGMII_RXCTL         )
 gpio-48  (RGMII_RXD0          )
 gpio-49  (RGMII_RXD1          )
 gpio-50  (RGMII_RXD2          )
 gpio-51  (RGMII_RXD3          )
 gpio-52  (RGMII_TXCLK         )
 gpio-53  (RGMII_TXCTL         )
 gpio-54  (RGMII_TXD0          )
 gpio-55  (RGMII_TXD1          )
 gpio-56  (RGMII_TXD2          )
 gpio-57  (RGMII_TXD3          )

gpiochip1: GPIOs 504-511, parent: platform/soc:firmware:gpio, raspberrypi-exp-gpio, can sleep:
 gpio-504 (BT_ON               )
 gpio-505 (WL_ON               )
 gpio-506 (PWR_LED_OFF         |led1                ) out lo ACTIVE LOW
 gpio-507 (GLOBAL_RESET        )
 gpio-508 (VDD_SD_IO_SEL       |vdd-sd-io           ) out hi 
 gpio-509 (CAM_GPIO            )
 gpio-510 (SD_PWR_ON           |sd_vcc_reg          ) out hi 
 gpio-511 (SD_OC_N
```

same thing if try to run `gpioinfo`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gpioinfo
gpiochip0 - 58 lines:
    line   0:     "ID_SDA"       unused   input  active-high 
    line   1:     "ID_SCL"       unused   input  active-high 
    line   2:       "SDA1"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line   3:       "SCL1"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line   4:  "GPIO_GCLK"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line   5:      "GPIO5"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line   6:      "GPIO6"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line   7:  "SPI_CE1_N"   "spi0 CS1"  output   active-low [used]
    line   8:  "SPI_CE0_N"   "spi0 CS0"  output   active-low [used]
    line   9:   "SPI_MISO"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  10:   "SPI_MOSI"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  11:   "SPI_SCLK"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  12:     "GPIO12"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  13:     "GPIO13"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  14:       "TXD1"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  15:       "RXD1"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  16:     "GPIO16"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  17:     "GPIO17"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  18:     "GPIO18"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  19:     "GPIO19"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  20:     "GPIO20"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  21:     "GPIO21"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  22:     "GPIO22"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  23:     "GPIO23"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  24:     "GPIO24"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  25:     "GPIO25"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  26:     "GPIO26"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
    line  27:     "GPIO27"      "sysfs"   input  active-high [used]
```

The situation is strange because first minute after kernel restart gpio pins are not occupied and I can run my program but then somehow they become "`used`" by `sysfs`. Even if I don't run any program situation is same. Of course it is possible to `unexport` each pin by `echo` in `sysfs` and run my program without problem but I can't understand reason of this behavior. How to find who is occupying `gpiochip0`?

Comment: This does not happen for me on a Pi400.  I can only assume you start a GPIO program which has this behaviour.  What GPIO related programs are you running?

Comment: @joan Thank you for reply. I am trying to control GPIO by ioctl() requests. The example could be find here on [github](https://github.com/Johannes4Linux/Linux_Embedded_Interfaces/blob/main/GPIO/gpio_ctrl.c) I guess that there is other program or service tries to use GPIO because on another OS image everything works without problem